# Rhino Mocks: Mocking a Read-Only Property declared on Interface

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have the following Interface and classes In a CSharp project:

```
namespace FakeLib
{
  public class Child : IChild
  {
    public DbConnection Connection { get; }
  }

  public interface IChild
  {
    DbConnection Connection { get; }
  }
  public class Parent
  {
    public IChild item { get; set; }
    public string Run()
    {
      return item.Connection.Database;
    }
  }
}
```

So I've create the following UnitTest method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  var repository = new MockRepository();
  var stub = repository.Stub<FakeLib.IChild>();
  stub.Stub(x => x.Connection).Return(new SqlConnection());
  var pai = new FakeLib.Parent() { item = stub };
  var conn = stub.Connection;
  Assert.IsNotNull(conn);
}
```

As far as I know, It should work without raising any exception. But the fact is that the "Connection" property is never returning the declared SqlConnection that should be stubbed by Rhino Mocks. Does anybody knows what did I miss?

Comment: What is the reason of the test failure?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough and thank you for your help.

The problem is that the Get Method from property "Connection" is not being stubed by Rhino Mocks. So, it raises a NullReferenceException first. And when debugging the test and trying to evaluate the property by the watch list, it raises an exception telling me that the get_Connection was not implemented. But I have checked the Rhino Mocks documentation and they told us to do exactly this:

    stub.Stub(x => x.Connection).Return(new SqlConnection());

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of different approaches, I've finally found the origin of this weird problem:

Replacing this code:

```
var repository = new MockRepository();
var stub = repository.Stub<FakeLib.IChild>();
```

with this one

```
var stub = Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateStub<FakeLib.IChild>();
```

Solved the problem. It's weird because the stubs were working fine, except on read only properties, that was this case. Seems that Rhino use different but ambiguous sintax for different goals. 
Thank you all for your help